# mysql join case count with single query

Tags: mysql, join, count, sum, case

i am very new to programming and now i have problem to solve it quickly. Trying  for 1weeks only and give some result that can satisfy me. Any one can help me with this, heres my table and result that i wanted to show:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BolZC.jpg)

this the result
[the problem ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BolZC.jpg)

i am trying and trying this code for more than a weeks and its still nothing:

```
enter code here SELECT idkt.id, 
    idkt.nama,
    idkt.satuan,
    trgt.nilai ,
    tbl.*,
    ROUND((tbl.Triwulan_1 / trgt.nilai * 100), 2) Persen_1,
    ROUND((tbl.Triwulan_2 / trgt.nilai * 100), 2) Persen_2,
    ROUND((tbl.Triwulan_3 / trgt.nilai * 100), 2) Persen_3,
    ROUND((tbl.Triwulan_4 / trgt.nilai * 100), 2) Persen_4
FROM indikator idkt
 left JOIN (
    SELECT id_indikator,
        YEAR(tgl) tahun,
        SUM(CASE
        WHEN MONTH(tgl) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN
            1
        END) AS Triwulan_1,
        SUM(CASE
        WHEN MONTH(tgl) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN
            1
        END) AS Triwulan_2,
        SUM(CASE
        WHEN MONTH(tgl) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN
            1
        END) AS Triwulan_3,
        SUM(CASE
        WHEN MONTH(tgl) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN
            1
        END) AS Triwulan_4

        FROM msttrans
        WHERE YEAR(tgl) = ".$tahun."
            GROUP BY id_indikator, YEAR(tgl)) tbl
    ON (idkt.id = tbl.id_indikator)
    left JOIN target trgt
        ON (trgt.id_indikator = idkt.id
            AND YEAR(trgt.tahun) = tbl.tahun)

left JOIN (select target.nilai as fnilai from target where id_indikator      is not NULL) trgt on trgt.id_indikator = idkt.id 

    ORDER BY idkt.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any inputs to arithmetic expressions like

```
 ROUND((tbl.Triwulan_1 / trgt.nilai * 100), 2)
```

are null, the resulting expression will also be null.  You probably should try changing these sorts of expressions from

```
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(tgl) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 1 END) AS Triwulan_1
```

to

```
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(tgl) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Triwulan_1
```

to avoid too many attempts to work with null values.

Also, you should troubleshoot by testing your inner queries one-by-one. Make sure they work (especially the one containing GROUP BY) before you use it in a join.

**Edit** `LEFT JOIN` operations with `ON` conditions that don't match any rows return null values for the columns in the left table. This is a common source of unexpected null values. (If you use `JOIN` in place of `LEFT JOIN` the query suppresses rows from the right table if they don't match the left table.)

You could troubleshoot these nulls with expressions like this.

```
SELECT ... tbl.Triwulan_1, trgt.nilai, ROUND((tbl.Triwulan_1 / trgt.nilai * 100), 2), ...
```

Comment: oh, thx ollie for advice, but can u give me a clue why my code here " ROUND((tbl.Triwulan_1 / trgt.nilai * 100), 2) Persen_1," return null value cos, its already exist in database, n why its same with column nilai on table target that doesnt shown?.. once again thx for fast respons

Comment: once again thanks a thousand for your advice, ollie, u saved my day, solved my problem can be easy without u THANKSSS